# How can I blend this white dot into the fabric background layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs5, blending

I'm working on an asset for a game mod, and I'm trying to put a custom logo on a banner texture. The banner behind the white dot/logo is a dark-red burlap texture, but I'm having issues with blending the dot into the fabric so it looks painted on or sewn into the banner.

[image]

I ran through all the layer mode options and none of them do the trick - they all make the dot disappear, turn bright pink, or turn flaming bright red.

I'm using Photoshop CS5, in case that matters. I assume there's some trick to this that I'm missing... maybe using the burlap pattern as a pattern overlay in blending options for the layer?

**How can I realistically blend this white dot into the fabric layer behind it?**

Answer (score 3):

1. Using the texture you already have as the background layer, draw a filled white circle on a layer above
2. Duplicate the background layer, and drag it above the circle layer.
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click between the two layers to clip the background layer copy to the white circle layer.
4. Set the layer blending mode of the background copy to Multiply
5. Add a Hue/Saturation adjustment layer to the circle layer, drag it above the background copy layer, and completely desaturate, and increase lightness a touch, as shown below
6. Add a Levels adjustment layer to the circle layer, drag it above the Hue/Saturation adjustment layer, and make adjustments to the levels sliders as shown below

[image]

7. To add a bit more realism, you could also select the background copy layer and apply *Filter > Render > Lighting effects*, with settings shown below. This will add more of a textured/embossed feel.

[image]

8. Further levels of realism are also possible, if you fill the entire circle layer with white, and save the image out as a displacement.psd file

[image]

9. Then, undo the changes to the circle layer, select the circle layer, and apply *Filters > Distort > Displacement*, set the horizontal and vertical scale to 2, and when prompted choose the displacement.psd you already saved as the source.

The result (shown below at 100% zoom) gives the illusion that edge of the circle is slightly distorted by the troughs and ridges of the texture

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is I find the shading that already exists in the background and simply brush it in onto the top layer, then add a few layers of textures to give it the painted effect.

The following is a quick example of what you can do. Don't mind the jank.

This one is with only the texture (without the shading) -

[image]

Whereas this one is with the shading -

[image]

**PROCESS I USED TO GET THIS RESULT:**

1. Find a desired texture. Desaturate it, change the levels (optional). Reduce the opacity to soften the sharp texture. Create a clipping mask to the white circle.[image]
2. Go to Select > Color Range and click on the shades. Increase or decrease the fuzziness based on how much you want to select. Click OK.[image]
3. Choose what color you want fill the selection with. It's usually the best to use the Eyedropper to choose a color that would be right beneath the paint.[image]
4. Fill the selection with a paint bucket tool or brush it on. Then, deselect.[image]
5. The edges will be quite sharp and jagged so a little bit of Gaussian blur doesn't hurt.[image]
6. All Done.